# mysql: get table names from another query

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation

There a similar questions to this but I can't quite get it to work.  I have 2 databases.  db 1 has user names

eg

```
userdb.usertable.username
```

db 2 has config tables for each user which are called

```
"their username" + _Config
```

I am trying to run a query that will loop through all the users of a specific type, get their usernames and then extract a value from their own config table.

this was close but would only work for 1 user.

```
SET @username:=(SELECT userdb.usertable.username FROM userdb.usertable WHERE version="free" );

SET @table:=concat(@username,"_Config");

SET @sql_text =concat("SELECT * FROM configdb.",@table);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;

EXECUTE stmt;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this seems like a poorly designed database

Comment: I'd second that. This seems like a spectacularly bad idea. Why would you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First off:*
**GET RID OF THIS DATABASE DESIGN IMMEDIATELY.**

99% of time you should not need two databases for a single application.

You may want to take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) too before going any further.

*Second*, it should be something like this:

```
Users_Table
id,username,(more user detail fields),config_value_1,config_value_2
```

Keep all of your user data in one table, unless a user can have more than one value for a config parameter. Then you would need a junction table like this

```
Users_Table
id,username,other fields

Config_Value_1_Table
value_id,name

Config_Value_1_Users
user_id,value_id
```

A common real world example of this could look like this:

```
users
id,first_name,last_name,username,password_hash,password_salt,email,is_admin,is_banned,is_active

locations
id,location_name

user_locations
user_id,location_id
```

then all you have to do is write a pretty simple query to get all of your user data

Comment: I'm happy to concede that the database is poorly designed - it was created years ago while I was learning mysql and PHP.  Also I appreciate your detailed response - it makes sense and I will use that approach in future. However, what I am wanting to do here is just a one off query so restructuring all the databases seems like overkill.  Is what I am wanting to do not even possible?  Thanks again - if I had enough rep to up vote your answer I would.

Comment: I found a workaround to get the data I needed.  Thanks anyway.